# Multiple answer with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem with `preg_replace` in PHP.

My text:

```
[Derp] a
• [Derp] a
```

My regex:

```
$simple_search[0] = '/\[(.*?)\] (.*?)/is';
$simple_search[1] = '/\• \[(.*?)\] (.*?)/is';
```

My subject:

```
$simple_replace[0] = "[color=#009D9D][$1][/color] $2";
$simple_replace[1] = "[color=#30BA76]• [$1][/color] [color=#92CF91]$2[/color]";
```

After `preg_replace`:

```
[color=#009D9D][Derp][/color] a
[color=#30BA76]#color=#009D9D][Derp][/color[/color] [color=#606090]: [/color]a
```

(it's a tool for coloring quotes)

**[Derp] a** and
**• [Derp] a** must not have the same color.

The problem is that the first search then replaces that this is not the right thing.

How can I detect that research is equal to the string?

Comment: What to search exaclty to replace ?

Comment: I want search 
• [Derp] a 
for remplace to
[color=#30BA76][Derp][/color][color=#606090]: a[/color]
but it's doesn't work because the search number 1 remplaces first

Comment: Like that `(• \[Derp\] a)` ? https://regex101.com/r/aE5qB1/1

Comment: I fail my comment, the real comment is :

 
I want search • [Derp] a for remplace to [color=#30BA76][Derp][/color][color=#606090]: a[/color] but it's doesn't work because the search number 1 remplaces first

Comment: Use `preg_replace_callback`, with a counter

Comment: Yes but the probleme is in FIRST

Comment: From your comment below `my code contains 22 options` - Does that mean you have 22 regexes working on the same string from the beginning? _If so_, how do you know a replacement is not something that will be found by the next regex? _If not_ and its done in a single pass, just move the important regexes up to the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your first regexp:

```
/(?<!\• )\[(.*?)\] (.*?)/is
```

means can not have front of the "[" an "•" and a space. Also if the • stands in beginning of your lines then you could put ^ front of it

Answer (score 0):

```
        $str = '[Derp] a
                • [Derp] a';

        $simple_search[0] = '/(\• )?(?P<m2>\[.*?\]) (?P<m3>.*)/i';

        echo $str = preg_replace_callback($simple_search[0],
            function ($m) {
                if (!$m[1]) return '[color=#009D9D]' . $m[2] . '[/color] ' . $m[3];
                else return '[color=#30BA76]• ' . $m[2] . '[/color] [color=#92CF91]' . $m[3] . '[/color]';
            }, $str
        );
```

result

```
[color=#009D9D][Derp][/color] a
[color=#30BA76]• [Derp][/color] [color=#92CF91]a[/color]
```

Comment: my solution is not for that case , you are right :),